# Dreaded Email notifications and Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, stripe

I seem to be having some issues with email notifications within Cartthrob at present. Now i know these have cropped up in the past, so I'm just trying to get my head around the best case scenario for this and the pitfalls to watch out for. Obviously the email notifications are pretty important for a client, and its a pain when they can be at times pretty hit and miss.

So I'm working on a clients site that we have switched to Stripe over PayPal which seems to be fine at present. The order confirmations are coming back ok, and the orders are been created in the Order channel.

But there are no notifications been sent out at all. This is currently on a development server for testing and I've gone ahead and tested that i can trigger the emails using:

```
<?php
if (mail('you@yourdomain.com', 'Quick email test', 'Is this on?'))
{
    echo 'Mail sent successfully.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Mail was not sent.';
}
```

And thats sending both using an email local to the development server and also the clients email. So i know thats working ok.

---

Ive also looked at the settings in the Cartthrob CP and made sure those notifications are correct.

[image]

Ive even simplified the templates been used right down to say literally Thanks for Ordering, Here is a new order etc. respectively. No extra tags or information.

---

I've also checked in the exp_cartthob_email_log and its saying that email_event has been completed. But nothing is arriving. SO totally baffled.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Ive also tested the Communicate from the clients email to mine and thats also working correctly.

Comment: Are you able to take a look at your servers email queue?

Comment: got my hosting people on the case looking into that, but i don't think thats the issue.. have just overwritten all the EE standard files, if nothing else to eliminate that its not that..

Comment: have tried all combinations now, php, sendmail, smtp and still nothing, its storing everything correctly in the orders along with the {customer_email} its just not sending anything out.

Comment: still at a loss.. I've tested everything i can think of here, and nothing is sending emails out... Orders are been saved with customer email, php email is working, communicate works fine.. at a total loss...

Comment: Checked the log and its saying that the email_event is complete... so just don't get this, have tried multiple email addresses and so on... just nothing is arriving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks to John Baxter i have the solution to all my issues with email notifications, but as I've said to John I'm both super pleased its solved but frustrated at the reason. So thought good to post..

Basically the option of Log Email.. if this is set to either NO, or Log but don't send then it doesn't send the notifications!.. now to me this means either log or don't log, or send the log.. not send the notifications at all? but I'm posting for others, and either way I'm appreciative for John and the heads up. Hope this helps others, or maybe its just me.

[image]